# Solving a surface integral using Gauss' Divergence Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Use Gauss's theorem to solve  $$\iint_S F\cdot n~dS$$ given $$F(x,y,z)=(x,xy,z)$$
where S is the surface $$x^2+y^2= z^2, z \in [0,1]$$

**My attempt:**

I have the solution and method for the question. The solution calculates Gauss' theorem as normal and attains the answer $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ whichI have managed to do. However it continues by calculating the surface integral for "the top of the cone" and subtracts this from the final answer. For every other question regarding Gauss' Divergence theorem I have never had to do this. What is the reason for this and how I can spot it in future questions?

How can you tell it is not a closed region. In another instance where S is the surface of a cylinder $$S = x^2+y^2 \le 1 , z \in [0,1]$$ and vector field $F(x,y,z)= (x^2y,z-xy^2,z^2) $ and the answer did not calculate the top or bottom of the cylinder.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The divergence theorem applies for "closed" regions in space. Meaning we have to close the surface before applying the theorem. Let $T$ be the (open) top of the cone and $V$ be the region inside the cone. We have $\partial V = S \cup T$, with that union being disjoint. Then $$\int_V {\rm div}\,F\,dV = \int_S F \cdot n\,dS + \int_T F\cdot n\,dS.$$

Comment: How can you tell it is not a closed region. In another instance where S is the surface of a cylinder $S = x^2+y^2 \le 1 , z \in [0,1]$ is closed. How can you tell whether it is closed or not?

Comment: That's why I used quotes.. the set $S$ is closed as a subset of $\Bbb R^3$ but it is not a "closed surface". You'd need to compute the surface integrals over the top and bottom too to apply the divergence theorem.

Comment: This is what I am saying. For the example I gave, the solution did not compute surface integrals over the top and bottom

Comment: Weird. Can you put here or in the original post the exact question?

Comment: Maybe depending on the field it was obvious that the integrals over top and bottom were zero. But I'm just speculating.

Comment: I have updated the original